# after pressing ctr alt f1 and rebooting I always have a black screen

Tags: linux, kde, kubuntu

In kubuntu, I originally tried to bring back the bottom bar of kde and when I pressed ctr alt f1, the command exit didn't work so I pressed the power button for reboot ... now kde never appears, (however it always) appears in the guest session, could you please tell me how to put back kde and the bottom bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The way to move away from the virtual console is with the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. In Ubuntu 17.10 and later press the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to exit from the virtual console.
2. The way to reboot the computer from the console is to login in the console and then run the command: `sudo reboot`.
3. To restore KDE and the bottom bar, try [How to revert KDE to its default settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114807/how-to-revert-kde-to-its-default-settings)
4. To reload KDE Plasma workspace in case it hasn't been completely loaded, run the following commands to stop KDE Plasma workspace and then restart it:

   ```
   killall plasma-desktop
   setsid plasma-desktop
   ```

Comment: I know about point 1 and 2, I tried to fix some things and now I can get the top bar by pressing alt + f2 and I can access the different folder by pressing alt + tab .... screen is still black however in the guest session it appears correctly ...

Comment: Try `killall plasma-desktop` (to stop it) and then after that `setsid plasma-desktop` (to restart KDE Plasma workspace).

Comment: I tried many things and now it works ... maybe the mv, thank you very much I'm quite relief, although the fiddling makes my computer longer to boot now hmmm

Comment: Wait and see what happens. After you update the kernel, it is normal for the computer to take longer to boot, and afterwards it returns to normal, so wait for a while and see if your boot time returns to normal by itself like it does following a kernel update.